# Subscribing to the API in Video Indexer Developer Portal fails due to too many redirects

Tags: azure-video-indexer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZseTD.png)
When trying to subscribe from below URL, it keeps failing due to too many redirects.

https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/products/authorization

Answer (score 0):

The site is undergoing an upgrade. See [my earlier question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742664/cannot-access-video-indexer-operations-api-key-anymore/66743471#66743471)
Patience is the only answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Video Indexer api-portal should be fully available for you from now on.

Video Indexer team.