# Cannot access Video Indexer Operations API Key anymore

Tags: azure, api-key, azure-video-indexer

I had previously subscribed to the video indexer API and have been using it for a couple of weeks.
Upon subscribing, there was a page to get access to the Primary and Secondary keys for the API for use on the server-side.
Just yesterday, I upgraded from my free trial account to an unlimited account and I noticed the site for the API documentation has undergone some maintenance, and lots of things have changed. The page for the API keys is not functional and neither is the subscribe link. My question is if there is a way to retrieve the key so I can continue working as I am pressed for time to deliver on this product.

Comment: I am currently facing this same issue too, there seems to be some restructuring on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api portal is currently being upgraded and were aware of the issues.
It is expected to be fixed soon.

Thanks,
VI Dev Team

Answer (score 1):

Video Indexer api-portal should be fully functional by now.

Video indexer team.